# Как поместить текст в QTextBrowser?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qt-designer, qtextbrowser

Пишу первую программу. Набросал дизайн программы в *Qt Designer*.

Не могу найти подходящий способ, чтобы 
поместить переменную **`a`** в поле: `textBrowser` (QTextBrowser), 
а переменную **`b`** в поле `textBrowser2` (QTextBrowser). 
Скрин ниже.

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

---

Смысл таков:

```
import random
a = random.randint (1,299)
b = 300 - a

print ("Сколько будет", a, "+",b,"?")
res = int(input("Введите  число: "))

while res != 300:
    print ("\nНе верно, попробуй ещё раз... ")
    res = int(input("Введите  число: "))

res = 300
print ("\n\n****Ахахааха... Ну Вы поняли****\n")
```

---

**design.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setEnabled(True)
        MainWindow.resize(224, 241)
        MainWindow.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 91, 21))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 180, 91, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter(self.centralwidget)
        self.splitter.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 100, 91, 61))
        self.splitter.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.splitter.setObjectName("splitter")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.splitter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.splitter)
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
        self.splitter_2 = QtWidgets.QSplitter(self.centralwidget)
        self.splitter_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 181, 31))
        self.splitter_2.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.splitter_2.setObjectName("splitter_2")
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.splitter_2)
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.splitter_2)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.textBrowser_2 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.splitter_2)
        self.textBrowser_2.setObjectName("textBrowser_2")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.splitter_2)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Суперпрограмма"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Сколько будет"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Окей?"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ:"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "+"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "?"))
```

**main.py**:

```
import sys
# Импортируем наш интерфейс из файла
from design import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # Здесь прописываем событие нажатия на кнопку        
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.MyFunction)

    # Пока пустая функция которая выполняется
    # при нажатии на кнопку                  
    def MyFunction(self):
       pass #заглушка
    
if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Судя по всему, `QTextBrowser` не совсем тот компонент, который Вам нужен. Я думаю, Вам больше подойдет `QTextEdit` или даже `QLineEdit`.

Comment: @Bogdan   а какая разница между QTextBrowser и QTextEdit / QLineEdit?

Comment: [документация](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextbrowser.html#details) Вам лучше меня объяснит

Comment: для Вашего случая я бы посоветовал `QLineEdit` с установленным readonly (если вы генерируете значение в программе). А для него уже использовать метод `setText`

Comment: @Bogdan      подскажите, пожалуйста .... как необходимо "обратиться", чтобы именно текст поступил в окно "Значение а"?

Answer (score 1):

Класс `QTextBrowser` предоставляет расширенный текстовый браузер с гипертекстовой навигацией. Этот класс расширяет `QTextEdit` (`в режиме только для чтения`).

main.py

```
import sys
# Импортируем наш интерфейс из файла
from design import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # Здесь прописываем событие нажатия на кнопку        
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.myFunction)

    # Пока пустая функция которая выполняется
    # при нажатии на кнопку                  
    def myFunction(self):
        self.ui.plainTextEdit.setText( 
            str(int(self.ui.textBrowser.text())+int(self.ui.textBrowser_2.text())))
        #pass

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

design.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setEnabled(True)
        MainWindow.resize(224, 241)
        MainWindow.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 91, 21))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 180, 91, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter(self.centralwidget)
        self.splitter.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 100, 91, 61))
        self.splitter.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.splitter.setObjectName("splitter")

        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.splitter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
#        
        #self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.splitter)
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.splitter)

        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")

        self.splitter_2 = QtWidgets.QSplitter(self.centralwidget)
        self.splitter_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 181, 31))
        self.splitter_2.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.splitter_2.setObjectName("splitter_2")

#        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.splitter_2) 
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.splitter_2) 

        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.splitter_2)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")

#        self.textBrowser_2 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.splitter_2)
        self.textBrowser_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.splitter_2) 

        self.textBrowser_2.setObjectName("textBrowser_2")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.splitter_2)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Суперпрограмма"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Сколько будет"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Окей?"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ:"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "+"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "?"))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: большое спасибо за наводку! 

Но в  данной случае, в окне (Сколько будет) 1 и 2 - числа должны генерироваться по принципу: 

a = random.randint (1,299)
b = 300 - a

Comment: @AlexandrS Одно другому не мешает. Удачи вам.

Comment: Большое спасибо!

+10 Вам к карме.

Comment: @217323 Подскажите, пожалуйста - каким образом можно вывести переменную "а" в окно 1,  соответственно и переменную "b" в окно 2???

Comment: @AlexandrS вы видимо хотите вставить текст в какой-то виджет. Я вам рекомендую сформировать новый вопрос. Приведите последний вариант вашей программы и сформулируйте понятный вопрос.