# Кодировка для QTextBrowser

Tags: c++, qt, кодировка

При подключении внешнего HTML-файла для QTextBrowser символы кириллицы отображаются некорректно из-за неверной кодировки. Пробовал использовать QTextCodec, но он не помогал. Код приведён ниже:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
  : QMainWindow(parent)
  , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
  QTextCodec* codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8");
  QTextCodec::codecForTr(codec);
  QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(codec);
  auto qb = ui->qtextbrowser;
  qb->setSource(QUrl("C:\\md.html"));
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/926166/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B2-qtextbrowser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение оказалось простым: нужно было просто указать кодировку UTF-8 в самом HTML-файле.

```html
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <p>абвгдеёжз</p>
</body>
</html>
```